# Accessing a function of a class from a function of another class

Tags: c#, function, object, inheritance, monogame

I am trying to access the Update function of Key from the Update function of MainChar. Both classes inherit from the Sprite class. In Main Char I am getting the error:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Key.Update(GameTime, List)'. I have tried putting the type before the parameters but I get the errors:

'GameTime' is a type, which is not valid in the given context, 
'Sprite' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

I have also tried creating a new instance of Key by doing:
Key key = new Key(texture, position);
I again tried putting the types before but just got:
Key does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments, and they aren't valid in the given context. Help would be apprieciated.

This question was associated with a similar question which did not solve my question because I can't make Update or Key static.

```
  public MainChar(Texture2D texture) : base(texture)
    {
        Scale = 0.1f;
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, List<Sprite> sprites)
    {
        Move();

        foreach (var sprite in sprites)
        {
            if (sprite == this)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (Velocity.X > 0 && IsTouchingLeft(sprite) || Velocity.X < 0 && IsTouchingRight(sprite)) 
            {
                Velocity.X = 0;
            }

            if (Velocity.Y > 0 && IsTouchingTop(sprite) || Velocity.Y < 0 && IsTouchingBottom(sprite))
            {
                Velocity.Y = 0;
            }

            if (sprite.rectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
            {
                hasDied = true;

            }

            if (sprite is Key)
            {
                Key.Update(gameTime, sprites);
            }
        }

        Position += Velocity;
     }
```

```
     public int keyCount;

        public Key(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position) : base(texture)
        {
            Position = position;
            Scale = 0.08f;
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, List<Sprite> sprites)
        {
            foreach (var sprite in sprites)
            {

                if (sprite is MainChar)
                {

                    if (IsTouchingLeft(sprite)  == true || IsTouchingRight(sprite) == true || IsTouchingTop(sprite) == true || IsTouchingBottom(sprite) == true)
                    {
                        Position = new Vector2(1000, 1000);
                        keyCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Update method of your MainChar class, after you check whether 'sprite' is an object of type Key (`if(sprite is Key)`), you also need to cast 'sprite' (which is an object *of type Sprite*) to type Key, e.g.: `((Key)sprite).Update(gameTime, sprites)`.

The Sprite class presumably does not have a callable Update method - this is why you're getting the error. The 'is' check does not automatically cast it to type Key, so even though you know 'sprite' has an *actual type* of Key, its *declared type* is still Sprite.

Comment: for a new contributor NICE, you beat me by a couple of secs but i like your answer more. Im sure in the latest .net 'is' will make it available, so if you was using a version which supported this it should cast as well on 'is'

Answer (score 2):

cmhoequist answer looks gd, try this tho if your using support version

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#a-nametype--type-pattern-a

```
if (sprite is Key k)
{
    k.Update(gameTime, sprites);
}
```